# django-rest-framework getting followers using related_name of ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

So I am creating follower system but there is a problem. Everything is working properly. but in follower serializer I  want the username's and other details of users.

models.py

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name="user" ,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    ''' to obtain user ' eeee = User.objects.first() , eeee.user'    '''          
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='following_user',blank=True)   
    ''' to obtain followers   ' eeee.following_user.all()'   '''
    ''' to obtain following   ' eeee.user.following.all()'   '''

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

In field following , *user.following.all()* is used to get the user in manytomany field of *request.user* and
*following_user.all()* is used get all the users who has added *request.user* in their following field.

serializers.py

```
class FollowerSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=False)
    follower = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        fields = ('user','follower')

 def get_follower(self, obj):
    context = self.context
    request = context.get("request")
    return request.user.following_user.all().values()
```

Here I am serializing all the user who has added *request.user* in their following field

views.py

```
class FollowerView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Follow.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FollowerSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

api

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "eeee"
    },
    "is_follower": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "user_id": 9
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "user_id": 16
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "user_id": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

These is the api I am getting of all the user who has added request.user in their following list.
the problem here is I am getting the *pk* of the user from the key *user_id*. But I want there username and other information like email, full name of the user who has that primary key. So how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the get_follower method in serializers.py as follows:

```
def get_follower(self, obj):
    context = self.context
    request = context.get("request")
    qs = request.user.following_user.all()
    data = [{'id': obj.pk, 'user_id': obj.user_id, 'name': obj.req_field} for obj in qs]
    return data
```